How to make list entry of many paragraphs?

List item

can be 1 line long only, right?

Actually, you can also use multiple paragraphs (in contrast to "lines") in a list.

To do this, simply indent the first line of the second paragraph
by one space (or more, how you like it).
I like this more than breaking lines by spaces, because the 
paragraph breaks make the text easier to read.
Here is the source code I used for this (excluding the source code itself):
Actually, you can also use multiple paragraphs (in contrast to "lines") in a list.

* To do this, simply indent the first line of the second paragraph
by one space (or more, how you like it).

 I like this more than breaking lines by spaces, because the
 paragraph breaks make the text easier to read.

- Here is the source code I used for this (excluding the source code itself):



Nope, looks like you can have multiple lines

line 1 of item one
line 2 of item one
Line 1 of item 2
Line 1 of item 3
Line 2 of item 3
Line 3 of item 3
Line 1 of item 4

To do this I just type <space><space> at the end of lines that should be under the same bullet or number. Then type <enter> and type the next line. It also appears to work for numbered lists.

Line 1 of number 1
Line 2 of number 1
Line 1 of number 2
Line 1 of number 3
Line 2 of number 3
Line 1 of number 4

Source Code


I can't edit your post, so I can't see the markup you're using. IMHO if edit is inactive, "view source" should be displayed instead.

I agree. I'm guessing we can't just enable that though.

I uploaded a screenshot which highlights the trailing spaces.

@HendrikBrummermann this doesn't work for me.
